# How to add value if condition match, python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to add "1" in each row for columns "Score"  where the below statement is true,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv(Path1 + 'Test.csv')
df.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
df[(df.Day7 >= 500)]
```

[Sample Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xTAK.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vLIj.png)

Comment: Please add samples in text form of input and expected output in your post and do let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 added sample value and require output details

Comment: As mentioned above it is always recommended to add samples of input and expected output in TEXT form, kindly do edit your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
df['score']=np.where(df['Day7']>=500,1,"")
```

Or as per OP's comment(adding @anky_91's enhanced solution here):

```
np.where((df['Day7']>=500)&(df['Day7']<1000),1,"")
```

When we print the value of `df` following will be the output.

```
    Cat          Day7    score
0   Advertisir   145    
1   Blogs        56 
2   Business     92 
3   Classfied    23 
4   Continuin    110    
5   Corporate    1974     1
```

Comment: yep, this is a good usecase for np.where also. +1

Comment: @anky_91, Thanks for encouragement buddy, learning from all greats(you are one of them too) pandas, cheers

Comment: Ha ha i am no where close. :D we all are learning. :) Thank you

Comment: @anky_91 any suggestion if wanted to use Day7 >= 500 with < 1000, and want same type of output

Comment: @MDSAQUIBNASIRKHAN use `np.where((df['Day7']>=500)&(df['Day7']<1000),1,"")`

Comment: @anky_91 hi, is it possible to put a condition like Day7 >= 500 scores 1, if  >=100 & < 500 sore 2, else 3.

Comment: @MDSAQUIBNASIRKHAN same like you do in np.where, but this time use [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for multiple conditions:

Answer (score 1):

You are halfway there. Just use `df.loc[mask, "Score"] = 1`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Day7":np.random.rand(5)*1000,
                   "Score": np.random.rand(5)})
print(df)
df.loc[(df.Day7>=500), "Score"] = 1
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.assign(Score=0)
df.Score = df.Day7 >= 500
```